# Gradle build project with specific jdk

Tags: java, grails, gradle, build.gradle

I am having Grails project (grails 2.3.11) with multiple Grails plugins. One main Grails project in addition of some user defined Grails plugins and core Java project creates a complete application. So far, these projects are build using Ant builder. Recently upgraded build process to use Gradle.

Problem with gradle process is that some project needs to be build with jdk 1.7 and some to be build with jdk 1.8. In order to fix it, I have set java_home to point to jdk 1.7. Then created gradle.properties file in project directories which needs code to be build with jdk 1.8. Have set property `org.gradle.java.home` to point to jdk 1.8. Now when I print java_home value from such project I found that it is still picking jdk 1.7 (the one set as environment variable).

**Here my gradle compileJava task:**

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    def env = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
    println "Compile Java: JAVAHOME = ${env}"
    dependsOn ':core:updateversiondotjava'
    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.DEBUG
}
```

Projects build with 1.7 are all Grails project and Grails user defined plugins. Reason to build them with 1.7 is to avoid grails version upgrade. Because grails 2.3.x or lower are not supporting Java 1.8.

Can anyone please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can achieve this using gradle's sourcecompatabity and targetcompatability  when you apply Java plugin. You can set different source & targets for subprojects.

Answer (score 0):

I recall Grails 2.3.11 running on Java 8 in my testing.  Early versions of Grails 2.3 did not run on Java 8.  I understand the official support started with 2.4.x but have you tried Java 8 with your 2.3.11 application?

Comment: Yes, have build application with Java 8 and Grails 2.3.11. It build without any error. Have upgraded to compatible plugins. But there is an error occur at run time, specifically speaking at Grails webflow - withForm() [duplicate form submission handler]. So it looks like at the time of building Java 8 is supported, but underlying things are not so compatible with the version.